# Find max number you can create from an array of numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, interview-questions

Was asked this in an interview yesterday:

You are given an array of numbers (not digits, but numbers: e.g. 9, 23, 184, 102, etc.) - you need to construct the largest number from it. For example: you get 21, 2, 10 - the largest number is 22110.

This is my solution, I wonder if you can improve this?

```
def maximum_number(a):
    work_dict = {
        0: 0,
        1: 0,
        2: 0,
        3: 0,
        4: 0,
        5: 0,
        6: 0,
        7: 0,
        8: 0,
        9: 0
    }

    for ai in a:
        # if ai is a single digit number, just add it
        if ai in work_dict:
            work_dict[ai] += 1
            continue

        # otherwise, decompose it to it's digits
        while ai > 0:
            number = ai % 10
            work_dict[number] = work_dict[number] + 1
            ai = int(ai/10)

    max_num = int('9'*work_dict[9] + '8'*work_dict[8] + '7'*work_dict[7] + '6'*work_dict[6] +
                    '5'*work_dict[5] + '4'*work_dict[4] + '3'*work_dict[3] + '2'*work_dict[2] +
                    '1'* work_dict[1] + '0'*work_dict[0])

    return max_num
```

Comment: So the task basically was to decompose the numbers into digits and then rearrange those digits to form the largest possible value that could be represented by these digits?

Comment: yeah... as I understood it

Comment: You're probably *not* allowed to decompose the numbers into digits. Why would they specify `not digits, but numbers` otherwise?

Comment: see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-of-numbers-arrange-the-numbers-to-form-the-biggest-number/

Comment: Firstly, you could use a list instead of a dictionary for `work_dict` if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, whenever you see this ... this is a big no-no:

```
'9'*work_dict[9] + '8'*work_dict[8] + '7'*work_dict[7] +
'6'*work_dict[6] + '5'*work_dict[5] + '4'*work_dict[4] +
'3'*work_dict[3] + '2'*work_dict[2] + '1'* work_dict[1] +
'0'*work_dict[0]
```

it could be replaced by a simple

```
''.join(str(i) * work_dict[i] for i in reversed(range(10)))
```

Of course, the initialization of the `work_dict` is similar.  And in fact, you don't need to initialize it if you take care to use `dict.get` instead of `dict[]`:

```
work_dict[number] = work_dict[number] + 1
# is equivalent to
work_dict[number] = work_dict.get(number, 0) + 1  # default to 0 if not in dict
```

Ps., whenever you are *counting* something, consider using [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

---

*Warning:*  The rest of this answer tries to address the problem that OP *say* they are solving in the comments to the question.  However, it is not certain that the understanding of the problem by the OP is correct.  From here on, we assume that you are allowed to shuffle all the input digits, whereas the original problem probably only allows shuffling around the numbers.

---

If you want to have it as compact and "functional" as possible, it would be much easier to just sort the entire input and output it:

```
def maximum_number(lst):
    return int(''.join(sorted(''.join(str(x) for x in lst), reverse=True)))
```

However, note that this doesn't work on the empty list (which might be okay, depending on the specification of the function).

It should also be mentioned that

1. it is harder to write than the "manual loop" variant, which can be important in an interview
2. it might be harder to read and thus to debug, but I believe that this is up to the eye of the beholder to determine

---

For complexity, this is *O(n log n)* whereas the optimal algorithm has running time *O(n)*.  We again see the trade-off between running time and readability.

Here is an *O(n)* algorithm using `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
def maximum_number(lst):
    counter = Counter()
    for elt in lst:
        counter += Counter(str(elt))
    return int("".join(str(i) * counter[str(i)] for i in range(9, -1, -1)))
```

Comment: This is very compact indeed. But is it in any way more performant than my code? I mean, both will find it in a magnitude of the sorting algorithm, which is on average O(n*log(n)), correct? You do get some optimization, from treating the num as a string though, so you save the deconstruction.

Comment: [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) also accepts `reverse=True` as argument, so you could get rid of the outer `reversed`.

Comment: @DavidRefaeli Updated in answer.  Added an O(n) algorithm using Counter instead of the manual dict approach.

Comment: No need to use `.get(...)` for the counter as per the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), missing elements have a count of `0`. You can also see this in the counter implementation that was already contained in my answer.

Comment: very nice! I was mistaken in my first comment - I don't have a sorting algorithm, so I think actually both mine and your updated is O(n), though yours is cleaner. I assume Counter does something very similar to what I did, only on strings.

Comment: @EricDuminil Thanks for the comment, I believe that I do answer the question as specified in the comment: _"into digits and then rearrange those digits to form the largest possible value that could be represented by these digits?"_ to which the OP answered in the affirmative.

Comment: @EricDuminil I added a note before the section where I start sorting and counting.

Answer (score 7):

### Your code

Your code as such seems to be functional, but not really elegant or concise.

First, the variable names don't speak for themselves. Nobody would be hurt if the function input was named `numbers` instead of `a` and `number` instead of `ai`. `work_dict` is also  not a particularly good name since it's very generic. How about `digit_histogram`?

Handling single digit numbers separately seems unnecessary. The algorithm you implemented can handle them without special treatment.

When constructing `max_num`, there is a lot of repeated code. You could simplify this using a list comprehension and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) (more on that soon).

### How I would have tackled this

Since we have the luxury that combination of these numbers should be maximized in base 10, we can get their digits simply by looking at their `str` representation (which coincidentally happens to be in base 10 ;-) )<sup>1</sup>.

If you include the other recommendations from above you end up with:

```py
def maximum_number_str(arr):
    digit_histogram = {
        "0": 0, "1": 0, "2": 0, "3": 0, "4": 0,
        "5": 0, "6": 0, "7": 0, "8": 0, "9": 0
    }
    # or: digit_histogram = {str(i): 0 for i in range(10)}

    for number in arr:
        for digit in str(number):
            digit_histogram[digit] += 1

    max_num = "".join(str(i)*digit_histogram[str(i)] for i in reversed(range(10)))

    return int(max_num)
```

Depending on how familiar you are with Python and if other modules are allowed, you could come up with a solution using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), or at least skip the dict initialization all-together if you use `.get(...)` instead of `[...]` when accessing the dictionary as presented by [Pål GD in is answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/223403/92478).

Just for reference, this is how it could look like using a `Counter`:

```py
from collections import Counter

def maximum_number_counter(arr):
    digit_histogram = Counter()

    for number in arr:
        digit_histogram.update(str(number))

    max_num = "".join(
        str(i) * digit_histogram[str(i)] for i in reversed(range(10)))

    return int(max_num)
```

---

### Edit: The other way to think about that task

There seems to be a vivid discussion here if you understood the task correctly. If you follow the arguments that speak against your and my former interpretation, this actually leads to another interesting problem.

I came up with the solution below, though I highly doubt that I could have come up with this in an interview situation.

```
from functools import cmp_to_key


def maximize_joint_number(number1, number2):
    joined12 = int(str(number1)+str(number2))
    joined21 = int(str(number2)+str(number1))
    return joined21 - joined12


def maximum_number(numbers):
    """
    Generate the largest possible number that can be generated rearanging the
    *numbers*, not the digits of the input sequence
    """
    return int("".join(str(i) for i in sorted(numbers, key=cmp_to_key(maximize_joint_number))))
```

The idea to this is actually from [this blog post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-of-numbers-arrange-the-numbers-to-form-the-biggest-number/) that was given in a comment by [Eric Duminil](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/139491). The [`cmp_to_key`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) trickery is needed because the `cmp` keyword was removed from sort in Python 3. You could also use `cmp_to_key` as a decorator, which makes it a little bit nicer:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

@cmp_to_key
def maximize_joint_number(number1, number2):
    ...

def maximum_number(numbers):
    return int("".join(str(i) for i in sorted(numbers, key=maximize_joint_number)))
```

A quick test seems to fulfill all the presented example outputs:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    assert maximum_number([0, 12]) == 120
    assert maximum_number([2, 21, 10]) == 22110
    assert maximum_number([9, 2, 5, 51]) == 95512
    assert maximum_number([20, 210, 32]) == 3221020
    assert maximum_number([1, 19, 93, 44, 2885, 83, 379, 3928]) == 93834439283792885191
```

The second and third test case break implementations that would try to use something like `sorted(numbers, key=str, reverse=True)` (lexicographical sort) directly.

---

<sup>1</sup> Thanks to [Peter Cordes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/50567) for [pointing out](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/223399/find-max-number-you-can-create-from-an-array-of-numbers/223402#comment433088_223402) the inaccurate wording here in earlier revisions.

Comment: Consider initializing (if necessary) the dict using dict comprehension `{ str(x) : x for x in range(10)}`.

Comment: @EricDuminil: I specifically ask the OP for this aspect, and he affirmed it. So technically at the time of writing the answer was valid.

Comment: @EricDuminil: I also included my take on that "alternative" (maybe correct) interpretation.

Comment: Perfect. I haven't seen an example for which `cmp=` is needed in a long time. Too bad it's been removed.

Comment: @EricDuminil: I haven't either. But it firmly stuck somewhere in the back of my head that it existed.

Comment: Already in base 10?? Huh?  The OP has binary integers, not strings.  Your own solution uses `str(number)` so you're already actively / explicitly converting from number to ASCII decimal string.  Maybe what you meant to say is that Python has an efficient int->string function built-in which happens to use base 10 :P.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Reworded that section.

Answer (score 7):

The question reads :

> You are given an array of numbers (**not digits**, but numbers: e.g. 9, 23, 184, 102, etc.) - you need to construct the largest number from it. For example: you get 21, 2, 10 - the largest number is 22110. (*Emphasis mine*)

In a comment it was stated :

> The task basically was to decompose the numbers into digits and then rearrange those digits to form the largest possible value that could be represented by these digits

Those two statements are very different and I'd tend to believe you either misunderstood the interview question or you didn't explain it properly. The example you gave, 22110 isn't constructed by the digits `[2,2,1,1,0]`, but by the numbers `[2,21,10]`. This fits much more with how you worded your question.

With your code, getting an input of `[20,210,32]` would yield the result `3222100`, but the actual answer should be `3221020` because of `[32,210,20]`.

At least, this is all assuming that the requirements that you put in your questions are specifically the one you received in the interview, meaning you misunderstood the question.

Comment: 3222100 is the correct max number, at least I think, as I don't have the question in front of me anymore - but there were enough examples from which I understood this. I emphasized the not digits to stress that you need to break the number into digits.

Comment: @DavidRefaeli It's hard to tell from the statement you gave in your question and it really feels like it's wrong. Are you sure didn't just see it this way? Because as I wrote, for the example you gave both explanations work.

Comment: You're 100% correct. The question is completely boring otherwise. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-of-numbers-arrange-the-numbers-to-form-the-biggest-number/

Comment: well, now I can't be sure... but could be. Who knows...

Comment: @EricDuminil Thanks I changed it :)

Comment: @EricDuminil oh god.. Ahah. It looks good now?

Comment: All good. I already upvoted yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @IEatBagels, it seems that you didn't understand the question. You're not allowed to split numbers into digits. You're only allowed to reorder whole numbers in order to get the maximum joined number. The output for `[0, 12]` should be `120`, not `210`!

Others answers are proud to be O(n) or O(n log n), but well, they're probably wrong.

So I'm proud to present this O(n!) solution:

```
from itertools import permutations

def joined_number(numbers):
    return int(''.join(str(number) for number in numbers))

max(permutations([20,210,32]), key= joined_number)
# (32, 210, 20)

max(permutations([1, 19, 93, 44, 2885, 83, 379, 3928]), key= joined_number)
# (93, 83, 44, 3928, 379, 2885, 19, 1)
```

The performance is horrible and it will fail for lists longer than ~10 elements, but at least you can play with it in order to understand what the *real* question was.

You can then try to look for the sort which could give you the correct answer.

Comment: Downvoter: constructive criticism is welcome.

Comment: I think the right algorithm / sort-order for this version of the problem is lexical sort according to the decimal string representations of the numbers. The largest leading digit goes first. The total number of digits is fixed, and a larger early digit trumps anything you can do later.  IDK if you left that out to avoid spoiling the problem for the OP; if so I can delete this comment.

Comment: @PeterCordes: If I understood your proposal correctly, the most straightforward implementation would be using `sorted(numbers, key=str, reverse=True)`. However, this does yield the wrong result for inputs like `[9, 2, 5, 51]` -> `[9, 51, 5, 2]` where it should be `[9, 5, 51, 2]` instead.

Comment: @AlexV: Ah, well spotted.  You're right, it's not as simple as I thought.  And it's not just leading digit then shortest, either.  Because `59` should sort ahead of `5`, but `51` should sort behind `5`.  But grouping by leading digit lets you cut down the brute-force search space by an order of magnitude until we think of something better than trying every possibility.

Comment: @PeterCordes: The simplest counter-example I could find is `[0, 1, 10]`. The problem is solved with "sorting by comparator" (see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-of-numbers-arrange-the-numbers-to-form-the-biggest-number/ and AlexV's answer, which are basically the same) but it would be interesting to see if there's any simple "sort by key" solution.

Comment: @EricDuminil: oh cool, until seeing the solution, it wasn't clear to me there was a transitive or whatever it's called property here that would allow a comparison sort, where `a < b` and `b < c` implies `a < c`

Comment: @PeterCordes: It's still not completely clear to me either. It seems to work fine but I've not seen any proof indicating that it is always the case.

Comment: @PeterCordes: `sorted(numbers, key= lambda i:itertools.cycle(str(i)), reverse=True)` would work if `cycle`s were comparable. They could be compared like lists, with some logic in order to avoid infinite loops.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: After talking to Baldrickk in the comments, I've realized that my sort by key method doesn't work for this problem. For instance, the below approach would sort [50,505040] as 50504050 instead of 50505040. I'm leaving the answer up for those who are interested.

---

This is my attempt at solving the problem assuming that the OP did indeed misinterpret the question and that the numbers can't be split up into digits. Going off of AlexV's answer I've come up with a simple sort by key solution (rather than sort by cmp). I would have posted this as a comment but I lack the reputation.

The first step is to realize that since the first digit is the most significant, the second digit the second most significant and so on, we can simply do an alphabetical sort.

```
def maximum_number(lst):
  return int("".join((str(n) for n in sorted(lst, key=str, reverse=True))))
```

So this will work for most cases.

But as AlexV pointed out in a comment, this neglects that, for instance, 5 should be sorted ahead of 51 (since 551>515), 1 ahead of 10, etc.

The key element to take note of here is that a number n that begins with a digit d should be sorted ahead of a number nk if k < d, but behind nk if k > d. If k = d, the order is arbitrary.
This can be adjusted for by appending the first digit of every number onto itself, yielding the following solution.

```
def sorting_key(num):
  num_str = str(num)
  return num_str + num_str[0]

def maximum_number(lst):
  return int("".join((str(n) for n in sorted(lst, key=sorting_key, reverse=True))))
```

This passes all examples I've seen posted in other answers.

---

Thanks to Baldrickk for pointing out that the first revision of this answer would fail at [50,501]

Comment: `maximum_number([50,501])`?

Comment: `2*str(num)` appears to be a better sorting key - I haven't checked to see it it is optimal

Comment: @Baldrickk Thanks for pointing that out. You can account for that by using the first digit, rather than the last. I've edited the answer occordingly.

Comment: ah, so my `2*str(num)` was overzealous - of course the most significant digit is the most important, and the digits beyond(/below?) that should be covered by the original ordering.

Comment: @Baldrickk Actually, after thinking about it some more, I realized that you were right, my method would dictate that [50,505] is arbitrary when it clearly isn't. But I'm afraid str(num)*2 is still not enough, because now [50,505040] is still sorted wrong. You continue this indefinitely, basically I think that sort by key just doesn't work for this problem.

Comment: hmmm I think we just need to find the correct key fn.  we have two competing issues - value of digits in increasing order (higher is better) and number of digits in decreasing order (less is more valuable)  We just need to find a way of bringing those two together

Comment: @Baldrickk Multiplying the string only creates a closer approximation of a number's real value as part of the resulting number. Without a ceiling on how large the numbers can be you would have to be infinitely precise. The only way I could see this happening would be by analyzing the list beforehand to find the largest number, then based on that we could know how much precision is required and therefore how many times to multiply the string. But that would defeat the point of a simple sort by key method in the first place, wouldn't it.

Comment: What's wrong with the comparator based solution in [my answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/223402/92478)? If you really want to go for `key`, maybe check the implementation of `cmp_to_key` to see if there are possible shortcuts.

Comment: @AlexV `cmp_to_key` just creates an object whose magic methods (`__lt__`, `__gt__`, etc.) call the supplied function. As for why do it instead of using a comparator function, to quote the [Python docs on sorting](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html#key-functions), `This technique is fast because the key function is called exactly once for each input record.` That and a user expressed interest in this method in the comments.

Comment: @BobRoberts: I'm aware how `cmp_to_key` works. Me question was mainly out of curiosity.

Comment: @AlexV: Having to use `cmp_to_key` isn't very elegant. It would be interesting to know if there's a good key function. In the meantime, `sorted(numbers, key=lambda i: str(i) * 1000, reverse=True)` should work fine for *many* examples, but isn't very elegant either.

Comment: @BobRoberts: `sorted(numbers, key= lambda i:itertools.cycle(str(i)), reverse=True)` would be nice. Sadly, cycles aren't comparable.

Comment: I've come up with (what I think is) a working key. (it passes @AlexV 's asserts)  It's actually in line with an earlier attempt, but with a minor tweak.  We were looking at sorting with strings, but sorting with lists as a key is subtly different. `k=list(str(num))``return k + k[0:1]` re-uses the adding the first character method, but in a way that sorts correctly. (though I came to it via an alternative approach this time).  I haven't been able to find a way to break it so far.  Now I guess we need to profile this vs the cmp approach. to see which is superior?

Comment: @Baldrickk That method fails on [50501,50] (5050150 instead of 5050501).

Comment: @BobRoberts ah, damn.  thanks. I'd actually tried `[50, 505, 5050]` as a test and it passed that...  needed to go a bit further...

Comment: Sigh... The whole code in Ruby would be `numbers.sort{|a,b| [b, a].join <=> [a, b].join }` because sorting by comparator hasn't been removed. Python is a great language with many good design decisions but this one doesn't feel right.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I came up with. It runs in O(n) because of the for each loop, and seems to be a nice readable option to me.

```
numberList = [1, 19, 93, 44, 2885, 83, 379, 3928]

def largestNumber(value):
    string = ''
    for number in value:
        string = string + str(number)
    result = ''.join(sorted(string, reverse=True))
    return(int(result))


print(largestNumber(numberList))


Output: 99998888754433332211
```

Your solution works in the same time complexity, so they are both on the same page in that regard, but stringing the values together and using python's built in sorting function saves some space and complexity.

Comment: The answer should be `93834439283792885191`.

Comment: Doesn't `sorted(string, reverse=True)` use an O(digits log digits)` sorting algorithm?  Or does Python use CountingSort for sorting the characters of an ASCII or UTF-8 strings to get `O(char)` complexity?

Comment: @PeterCordes There's not much difference between O(n.log n) and O(n) anyway, but I'm pretty sure the complexity will be O(n. log n) here.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I know the time complexity of the sort is O(n log n) because Python uses Timsort, but the overall time complexity should still be O(n) since the for each loop iterates over every item of the input numberList, right?

Comment: `N * log(N)` grows more quickly than `N`, by an extra factor of `log(N)`.  So it dominates the for-loop's time.  You have `O(N  + N*log(N) )` which simplifies to `O( N*log(N) )`

Comment: @PeterCordes Yep, my bad. I think I got it confused with just O(log n), and forgot which one grows faster. :)

Comment: IDK how you can forget that `N * log(N) > N` for large N.  You can tell just by looking at it, or thinking of a simple number like `100`.  With base-10 logarithms, `log10 (100) = 2`, so N log N has already grown twice as large as just N.  (In general for any `N` larger than `e` or `10` or whatever base you choose, `log(N)` is greater than 1).   Maybe that method will help you avoid making the same mistake in the future by thinking about the expressions you're writing instead of only trying to memorize facts.